# How do I make an image fit css grid without the image expanding the size of the column?

Tags: html, css, image, multiple-columns, css-grid

So I want to add an image to one of the middle columns in my grid.

[The grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTBBe.png)

But when i add the image the column expands

[Grid with the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f2DN.png)

How do scale down the image so that its width is the same as the columns width?

```css
.game-box {
       position: relative;
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: 100px auto auto 100px;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       background-color: rgb(224, 142, 142);
       width: 900px;
       height: 700px;
       transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    
    }
```

```html
 <figure class="image-box">
            <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.DYZMAUANlCkZudy3ecHIjgHaFj%26pid%3DApi&f=1" class="image">
 </figure>
```

Comment: 1fr instead of auto

Comment: ^ also minmax(0,1fr)

Comment: `img { width: 100%; }` works aswell. then the image only takes up 100% of the column width.